# Java Gradle Composite build could not resolve issue

Tags: java, gradle

I have two projects A and B which are inside one repository. B uses some functions from A so I want to compile A before running B. I found out this can be done using Gradle composite build. I created Gradle projects like below structure.

**Structure:**

```
|
|--A
|   |src
|   |build.gradle
|   |settings.gradle
|
|--B
|   |src
|   |build.gradle
|   |settings.gradle
```

**A.build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'

    group "com.check"
    version "1.0"

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**A.settings.gradle:**

```
rootProject.name = 'A'
```

**B.build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'idea'

group "com.check"
version "1.0"

mainClassName = "com.check.B.Inititate"

dependencies {
    compile "com.check:A:1.0"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

**B.settings.gradle:**

```
rootProject.name = 'B'
```

**B project initiate method:**

```
package com.try.run;
import com.check.A.check;
public class Initiate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(check.ret());

    }

}
```

While building this using gradle I get below error

```
CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.268 secs
Could not resolve: com.check:A:1.0
```

Note: I am using ecilipse Oxygen version and run refresh gradle project to build the project

Comment: In your example, you have `subprojects` block in **A**'s `build.gradle` - that won't apply it to the root project. Also, how are you telling Gradle about the composite build setup? Are you using `--include-build` in the CLI or are you trying to use `includeBuild` in **B**'s `settings.gradle`?

Comment: @mkobit I missed to include build. Please find my answer below. Kindly let me know if any thing more should be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to add the following line on **b.settings.gradle:**

**b.settings.gradle:**

```
includeBuild  '../A'
```

After which it worked perfectly.